# Material UI Raised Button not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm literally copying the code verbatim from Material UI (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button) for the raised button. I've installed all the necessary node modules. What is happening?

Attached the error below image. Basically it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined".

[image]

```js
<RaisedButton label="Primary" primary={true} style={style} />
```

Comment: Can you add more.  Like the full error stack and the full component that's throwing the error.

Comment: Just added picture

Comment: Show more code please.

Comment: The problem is inside raisedbutton so either the style your applying it is throwing an error. Or raisedbutton is missing some dependancies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined while trying to open a Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045594/getting-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-preparestyles-of-undefined-wh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your topmost component (or at least some parent component) in 
material-ui's MuiThemeProvider component:

https://jsfiddle.net/9017dsc2/1/

```
import React from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton label="A Raised Button" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <Example />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```

Comment: cool - this solved it for me! I just added "import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';" and it worked. thanks

Comment: awesome, glad you got it working! I edited my answer to include the imports to improve the answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `style` attribute is undefined. Please have a look at code of [document page](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button):

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

const style = {
  margin: 12,
};

const RaisedButtonExampleSimple = () => (
  <div>
    <RaisedButton label="Default" style={style} />
    <RaisedButton label="Primary" primary={true} style={style} />
    <RaisedButton label="Secondary" secondary={true} style={style} />
    <RaisedButton label="Disabled" disabled={true} style={style} />
    <br />
    <br />
    <RaisedButton label="Full width" fullWidth={true} />
  </div>
);

export default RaisedButtonExampleSimple;
```

There is a constant style:

```
const style = {
  margin: 12,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This question should be closed and or downvoted as it has already been asked and answered here: [Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined while trying to open a Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045594/getting-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-preparestyles-of-undefined-wh/41052954#41052954)

I don't have the rep required to handle this but we shouldn't have multiple questions on here to the same thing.

Comment: Because material-ui documentation is screwed up. Question is fine.