# transpiled.js:35999 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Unable to render cards using react, it returns with error

**"transpiled.js:35999 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined"**

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI9OM.png)

[image: Please check the code here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045594/cannot-read-property-preparestyles-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement for the `Card` component is wrong.

Change this;

```
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card'
```

with this

```
import { Card, CardActions, CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card'
```

**Update**

You need to wrap you app with `MuiThemeProvider` like described in [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import MyAwesomeReactComponent from './MyAwesomeReactComponent';

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <MyAwesomeReactComponent />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Thank you Benny, but it still resulted in the same issue. :(

Comment: @PremKumar Can you add the complete error to your question please

Comment: transpiled.js:1010 Warning: Failed context type: The context `muiTheme` is marked as required in `Paper`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Paper (created by Card)
    in Card (created by App)
    in App

transpiled.js:35997 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined

Comment: Thank you, that works fine , but i'm unable to update cards into it which is required :( , like this 
https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/demos/cards/

Comment: Thats another broad topic. I suggest you to read some tutorials about react with a quick google search and then decide what you want to do.